# shell_exec is not executing as expected

Tags: php, shell

I wan't to execute shell script with PHP code which will check if git branch is up to date or push or pull is needed. When i run my code i get error.

This is my code

```
$check = shell_exec(
'LOCAL=$(git rev-parse @)
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse @{u})
BASE=$(git merge-base @ @{u})

if [[ $LOCAL = "$REMOTE" ]]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
elif [[ $LOCAL = "$BASE" ]]; then
    echo "Need to pull"
elif [[ $REMOTE = "$BASE" ]]; then
    echo "Need to push"
else
    echo "Diverged"
fi');
var_dump($check);
```

And this is the error / response which im getting

```
sh: 5: [[: not found
sh: 7: [[: not found
sh: 9: [[: not found
string(9) "Diverged
"
```

So how should my code look like in order to start working? If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you

Comment: `[[` is a bash-builtin.

Comment: Have you tried if `if [ "$LOCAL" -eq "$REMOTE" ]` ?

Comment: if i replace all double square brackets with one then i get sh: 5: [: =: unexpected operator

Comment: replace `=` with `-eq`

Comment: ah soory @AshishK, your first comment is working

Comment: Please write an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because `[[` is a bash-builtin. This may work for you.

```
$check = shell_exec(
'LOCAL=$(git rev-parse @)
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse @{u})
BASE=$(git merge-base @ @{u})

if [ "$LOCAL" -eq "$REMOTE" ]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
elif [ "$LOCAL" -eq "$BASE" ]; then
    echo "Need to pull"
elif [ "$REMOTE" -eq "$BASE" ]; then
    echo "Need to push"
else
    echo "Diverged"
fi');
var_dump($check);
```